# Cannot determine type of undefined()

Tags: javascript

Recently I investigated a situation in which a programmer inadvertently passed `undefined` into addEventListener, thus:

```
window.addEventListener('load', undefined);
```

No error was thrown.  It's as if JavaScript is willing to invoke `undefined`.  But what in the world *is* `undefined()`?  I have tried all sorts of things, e.g.:

```
console.log(undefined() === null);
console.log(typeof undefined());
```

but I never get anything back.

**Edit added for clarity**:  My original question was based on a mistake, as I had not set my Developer tools to log errors to the console.  The above two commands (but not the call to `addEventListener`) DO throw errors in a browser, as answers and comments below indicate.

Comment: Undefined is not a type, it's undefined.

Comment: I know that `undefined` is not a type.  My question is about the status of `undefined()`, which raises no syntax errors in JavaScript.

Comment: It _is_ weird-- if you just try to call undefined as a function in the console it throws an error, but if I pass any non-function as the callback into `addEventListener` it just silently fails with no error raised...

Comment: You're both wrong... `undefined` is its own type: `typeof undefined === 'undefined'`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is correct - undefined is a primitive type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Data_structures_and_types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's as if JavaScript is willing to invoke `undefined`.

No, [`addEventListener` is specified to ignore `null`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener), [which JavaScript’s `undefined` is converted to](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-nullable-type). `undefined` is never called.

Further proof that JavaScript is not willing to invoke `undefined`, in a browser:

```
> undefined()
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: I think on the right track, but it seems like perhaps browsers went above and beyond on the spec, because I can do it with other non-functions-- like `document.addEventListener('click', 3)` -- the browser doesn't complain it was passed a non-function, but when I then click in the document it doesn't raise any sort of error...

Comment: Yes, maybe it's just what the browsers being tolerant.  I just now tried `console.log(undefined())` in Node and got "Reference Error:  undefined is not a function."

Comment: @AlexanderNied: Ah, that’s a Chrome thing. Firefox only ignores `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @Ryan Have you considered submitting a pull request to update the linked specification to substitute _"2. If callback is null or undefined, then return."_ for _"2. If callback is null, then return."_ ?

Comment: Responses so far have been very helpful.  This one summarizes best, for me, the points that held up.  I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will return:

> Undefined is not a function

```js
console.log(typeof undefined());
```

If you run it console on a browser it will return undefined not a function. Undefined does not have any value unlike `null` which is an object.

Comment: Yes, in Node, but not in my browser.  See comment to answer below.  I think we've pinned it down as strictly speaking an error that browsers tolerate.

Comment: @HomerWhite: `undefined()` should definitely throw an error in your browser. You might not be looking for errors in the right spot…?

Comment: I would recommend changing the snippet to `undefined()` for clarity. Some might misunderstand that the rest of the context there is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ryan, you are correct.  I had not checked the Errors option.

Comment: @HomerWhite It will throw error for sure. Please make sure that the code is running and you are looking at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

`null` means that something exists, but has been told it has no value.
`undefined` means that thing has not been given a value, usually because it hasn't been declared/initialized.

In Javascript, `undefined` is a primitive. It's falsey, so it evaluates to `False` if used in conditional.

Javascript is not a strongly typed language, so there's nothing to check that a callback function *is* a function until it's called. In fact Javascript doesn't care how many arguments are passed or what their type is, everything's just dumped in when a function is invoked, and it's up to the function how to handle the arguments.

For example in many enumerable methods, they pass back to you `(index, value, array)`. It doesn't matter if your function looks for these values or assigns them a temporary variable, they're still passed. Both `a.forEach(function(index){}) and a.forEach(function(){})` actually have access to all 3 of the variables mentioned.

Comment: *“Javascript is not a typed language, so there's nothing to check that a callback function is a function.”* How about `typeof`? Anyway, if you tried to call a non-function *without* checking, it would throw an error, not fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to find the type of passed arguments:

```
var myVar;

Object.prototype.toString.call(myVar);
```

and it will return `"[object Undefined]"`

same for other use cases like if `myVar` is a string as below:

```
var myVar = 'It is a string';
Object.prototype.toString.call(myVar);
```

it will retrun `"[object String]"`